# data sending from server to client-side Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest

I made a post request. I want to perform some operations and to send back data to the client-side based on which my frontend will change. How to do that??

Comment: You could simply have your frontend make a second GET request to retrieve the new data and update itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get a response to the post request after you make the changes.
If the changes take too much time and cause a timeout, There are two possible ways to proceed:

1. Set a timeout in frontend and make a get request to fetch the data.
2. Look into [socket.io](https://socket.io/docs/v4/). (This is a better way of handling things
   as you can set a listener on frontend to receive any data from
   backend.)

Answer (score 0):

In the server side you can write

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.listen('3000')

app.post("/getdata", (req, res) => {
    res.send(//any json data)
})
```

in your client side you can write

```
var output = false
fetch("your server link or if you are on local server then 
http://localhost:3000/getdata", {method: 'POST'})
.then(data => {return data.json()}).then(data => {output = data})
```

now you have your result in var output of your client side webpage

Comment: the page redirects to the json output which I am sending. I want to stay on the previous page and make changes to that one